# I want to go through an API data and display it with print in my console

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

when I try to display the number of cases and name of the country from all the countries it gives me an error, i tried many ways without success.

here is the code:

```
url = "https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries"

    response = requests.get(url).json()

    
    j = range(0, 10)
    

    all = {
        'country': response[i]['country'],
        'confirmed': response[i]['cases'],
    }

    for i in j:     
        for i in response:                              
            print(all)
```

Comment: your code is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests

url = "https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries"

response = requests.get(url).json()
data = []

for line in response:
    tmp = {}
    tmp['country'] = line['country']
    tmp['confirmed'] = line['cases']
    data.append(tmp)

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution but you have to know the number of countries in the API.

here it is:

```
url = "https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries"

    response = requests.get(url).json()

    
    i = 0
    

    for i in range(0, 189):
        all = {
        'country': response[i]['country'],
        'confirmed': response[i]['cases'],
        }
        print(all)
```

Comment: You can get the length by calling len(response)

Comment: I checked it and it worked, but it was unorganized. the other solution I found was organised. thank you so much.